# arm-GCC to compile asm file

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile a simple "asm" file with GCC to understand the compilation. 
test.h:

```
#define APPLICATION_EXIT .end
```

test.asm:

```
#include "test.h"
APPLICATION_EXIT
```

when I run :

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc-9.2.1.exe -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mthumb -g -c .\test.asm
```

I got :

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc-9.2.1.exe: warning: .\test.asm: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

but there is nothing generated , no "out' file.
I try to run

```
arm-none-eabi-as -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mthumb -g -c .\test.asm
```

I got :

```
.\test.asm: Assembler messages:
.\test.asm:2: Error: bad instruction `application_exit'
```

It looks like the AS works but the Macro doesn't work. 
when I change the test.asm to :

```
#include "test.h"
.end
```

`arm-none-eabi-as -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mthumb -g -c .\test.asm` 
works. I got a.out.

Did I use GCC wrong? whey Gcc is not able to run the backend "as" directly?
Why the #define Macro doesn't work? 
Thank you so much, I appreciate any comments.

Comment: Note that the `.end` directive like doesn't do what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in [the gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options) which filename extensions are recognized.  `.asm` is not listed as assembly language source files in Unix are traditionally named `.s`, or `.S` (capital S, remember Unix filenames are case sensitive) if they are to be passed through the C preprocessor.  (C-style macro and include expansion are handled by the C preprocessor, not by the assembler itself, which is why it doesn't work when you run `as` directly.)

Files not otherwise recognized are assumed to be object files to be passed to the linker, but since you specified `-c`, the linker is not to be run, so `gcc` thinks there is nothing to do.

You can either rename your file to end in `.S`, or use the option `-x assembler-with-cpp` to explicitly tell gcc what to do with this file.  Or, you can first run `cpp` on your file to expand the macros and includes, and then run `as` on the resulting output (or pipe one into the other).

Comment: Thanks, Nate. I tried to change the file name to .s wich will work the same way as "arm-none-eabi-as", got the same error "bad instruction `application_exit'", could you please give me more information your "expand the macros and includes"?  how to do that? My understanding is that use some command to get some temporary file then use AS to compile to get the "a.out", am I right?

Comment: I tried to compile the test.asm with  arm-none-eabi-gcc-9.2.1.exe --specs=nosys.specs -x assembler-with-cpp -c .\test.asm  Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Daniel You need `.S` (capital S) for the file extension if you plan to use the preprocessor.  Not sure how this works on Windows.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, directives such as `#define`, `#include` are processed by the same preprocessor program that the C compiler uses.  It is called `cpp`, though I don't know where it would be installed on your system.  You can run `cpp test.asm` and the output will be a file with all the macros and includes expanded.  You can then run `as` on the resulting file.

Comment: @Daniel: Also note that running `as`, or compiling with `-c`, will only produce an object file (`.o`).  If you want the executable, you also have to run the linker (`ld`) or else run `gcc` without `-c`.  If you have questions about how to do that, better to ask another question (after checking the documentation for yourself).